# Is it legal to open a company in Canada whose primary commercial activity is stock trading?

Tags: canada, tax-law, limited-liability-company

Is it possible for an individual in Canada to open a company whose primary activity is trading stocks? That is, a person trades stocks under the name of the company they open. Is it legal to do so?

Comment: Is it the corporation's own money or is the company trading with money from someone other than its equity investors? The former is a personal investment company, the latter is a stock brokerage or private equity fund. Regulation of the two kinds of activities is very different.

Comment: @ohwilleke trade using the company's own money--basically means my money only

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? To protect yourself from liability? Essentially all publicly-traded stocks already carry limited liability. Are you going to be trading on margin and want to make sure that, if you get a margin call, you can walk away and let the company go bankrupt?

Comment: I am trying to get the benefit of both revenue and lost so that I pay less tax when I earn money while also be more protected from losses.